# net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_RESPONSE.NotSameOriginAfterDefaultedToSameOriginByCoep 200

Tags: node.js, heroku, mern, cloudinary, cross-origin-embedder-policy

Please help solve this problem.
I am working with a MERN app.
In the app, I upload images to the cloudnary using the API.
Then I upload the image on the frontend using secure_url.
It works on localhost but does not work on heroku i.e. the image is not uploaded

localhost:

[image]

heroku:

[image]

Response in browser console:

[image]

other images:

[image]
[image]

upload.js

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const cloudinary = require("cloudinary");
const { verifyTokenTeacher } = require("./verifyToken");

cloudinary.config({
  cloud_name: process.env.CLOUD_NAME,
  api_key: process.env.CLOUD_API_KEY,
  api_secret: process.env.CLOUD_API_SECRET,
});

// upload image
router.post("/upload", verifyTokenTeacher, (req, res) => {
  try {
    console.log(req.files);
    if (!req.files || Object.keys(req.files).length === 0)
      return res.status(400).json({ msg: "Fayl yuklanmangan" });

    const file = req.files.file; // oxiridagi file bu query parametr
    if (file.size > 1024 * 1024 * 2)
      return res.status(400).json({ msg: "Fayl hajmi 2mb dan kam bo'lsin" });

    // if file no image
    if (
      file.mimetype !== "image/jpeg" &&
      file.mimetype !== "image/jpg" &&
      file.mimetype !== "image/png"
    )
      return res.status(400).json({ msg: "Faqat JPEG va PNG rasm yuklang!" });

    cloudinary.v2.uploader.upload(
      file.tempFilePath,
      { folder: "test1" },
      async (err, result) => {
        if (err) {
          throw err;
        }

        return res
          .status(200)
          .json({ public_id: result.public_id, url: result.secure_url });
      }
    );
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(500).json(err.message);
  }
});
```

using image url in frontend:

```
<img src={question.image.url} alt="Rasm"  />
```

question model: Question.js

```
    const mongoose = require("mongoose");
    const questionSchema = mongoose.Schema(
      {
        title: {
          type: String,
          required: true,
        },
        themeId: {
          type: String,
          required: true,
        },
        image: {
          type: Object,
          default: null,
        },
      },
      {
        timestamps: true,
      }
    );
    
    module.exports = mongoose.model("Question", questionSchema);
```

create question router: questions.js

```
router.post("/", verifyTokenTeacher, async (req, res) => {
  try {
    await Theme.findById(req.body.themeId);
    const newQuestion = new Question(req.body);
    const savedQuestion = await newQuestion.save();
    res.status(201).json(savedQuestion);
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(500).json({ msg: err.message });
  }
});
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I was getting the same error while fetching images from cloudinary.

I resolved the error by adding `crossorigin="anonymous"` in image tag.

Just add `crossorigin="anonymous"` in your img tag like:

```
<img crossorigin="anonymous" src="https://example.com/image.jpg">
```

this should resolve the error.

Answer (score -1):

I see the error you get is
"net::
ERR_BLOCKED_BY_RESPONSE.NotSameOriginAfterDefaultedToSameOriginByCoep 200"

Would you try adding this header to tell the client browser that it is allowed to fetch resources from the Cloudinary domain?

Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://res.cloudinary.com/

If this does not resolve the issue, please submit a ticket at http://support.cloudinary.com and we will take a deeper look.

Answer (score -1):

In my case, it was caused by `Cross-Origin-Embedder-Policy: require-corp` (probably clashed with another header, not sure which one).

Fixed by replacing with `Cross-Origin-Embedder-Policy: same-origin`.

Comment: `same-origin` is not a valid value for the `Cross-Origin-Embedder-Policy` header.


`Cross-Origin-Embedder-Policy: unsafe-none | require-corp | credentialless` (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cross-Origin-Embedder-Policy)

What's probably happening in your case is that the browser is defaulting to `unsafe-none`, since it doesn't understand the value for that header.

Comment: @barryels have you tried to search by that value on that page?